# Verify software is not harmful before upload to my server?

Tags: web-application, file-upload

I am writing a web application that allows uploading of software to my server for other users to download (file hosting). How can I verify that a program is not harmful before it is uploaded it to my server?

Comment: Why not use an anti-virus (the de facto tool for exactly this situation)?

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, this is impossible.

There is a result from theoretical computer science called the ["Halting Problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). It states that you can never write a program that, for any other program, can prove whether it will terminate.

Now, if you can't even prove that a random program will terminate, you certainly can't prove that it is harmless.

The only way to do this is to make sure the programs uploaded are **very** limited in what they can do. Probably limited beyond the point where they are useful.

You can add virus checks to your service (as is also suggested in [thel3l's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/155822/5405) and [schroeder's comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/155820/verify-software-is-not-harmful-before-upload-to-my-server/155824?noredirect=1#comment296102_155820)). I've seen more hosting services do this, and it will at least protect your downloading users a bit.

However, you will always be in the arms race between malware makers and virus scanners. You cannot guarantee to your users that the software hosted is safe. You can, however, keep out some bad apples - and hopefully, most bad apples.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in two ways:

1. Sandbox. Sandbox everything, always execute code *only* inside one and never outside.
2. **Don't execute the code**: this is probably easier. Just ensure that your parser never loads the entire code into memory and runs it during upload.
3. Compress. This prevents the code from being executed during and after upload. Recommended with a sandbox.

Additionally, you may want to consider putting your code that is being uploaded into an external storage site so as to help prevent a full compromise if someone manages to execute code.

And as @iain said, you may want to consider scanning all incoming files for known viruses.

Comment: How can i do the virus scan. Should i use an anti-virus? if yes what anti-virus can i use?

Comment: @user3579115 - yes. You can either use a conventional AV solution or something more proactive like Cuckoo Sandbox. I'm not sure which platform you'll be working on, but I'm sure you can find some free alternatives that you can pragmatically use to scan new files.

Comment: I am planning to use Ubuntu as operating system